# cPanel mysql error 0

Tags: mysql, database, connection, cpanel

I was trying to connect to my mysql server via PHP webpage, and after some time, I figured out that it returns error 0.

Some details:
I am running a webserver with cPanel, and it also includes mysql service. Now I have made a simple webpage, with connecting to my database:

```
mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die ('cannot connect to sql server: '.  mysql_errno());
```

When running this,  I got the output:

```
cannot connect to sql server: 0
```

What I have already figured out, is that it must have something to do with a mysql service bug, and some people (on the internet) suggest to re-install mysql, although  I don't believe that such an error requires such a radical "change". Also, on the other hand to access cpanel via SSH (for re-install or system restart), I would need access to cPanel WHM, which I currently don't have.

Do you have any advice for me on what  I shall do? If necessary, I can try to get access to WHM.

The whole code:

```
<?php


ini_set('display_errors',1);
$mysql_hostname = "****";
$mysql_user =  "****";
$mysql_password =  "****";
$mysql_database = "****";


// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die ('cannot connect to sql server: '.  mysql_errno().  mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('cannot select db: '.mysql_error());

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried doing the same stuff with mysqli_* (as there seems to be no PDO extension installed), but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's help. It seems that I have solved the problem now, although I am not sure what the bug was. I have taken several actions:

- reset password for mysql user
- Used mysqli* method
- used try-catch method in the php script.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 0 indicates that the MySQL Wizard was unable to install, start or configure the new server. Usually removing the installed instances and reset it up will help to resolve this.

Try

1.OPEN mysql in explorer

2 Run mysql_uninstallservice

3.Run mysql_installservice